# Make a list for n from 2 to 10 of array plots for x and y up to 50 x^y mod n

Tags: plotting, numerics

> 

```
Table[ArrayPlot[Mod[x, y, n]], {n, 10}, {x, 1, 50}, {y, 1, 50}]
```

> expected answer
> [[image: expected image][1]]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for plots variing with n try

```
GraphicsRow[Table[ArrayPlot[Table[Mod[x, y, n] , {x, 1, 50}, {y, 1,50}]], {n,    10}]]
```

[image]